# Need to end a loop of a subprocess through userinput (GPIO.input)

Tags: python, bash, subprocess, record, raspberry-pi2

I need to execute a bash-command in a python program on a raspberry pi, which starts a record, which really starts recording if their is the sound above a certain frequency and finishes after 8sec or if there is silence. After a record finished, it starts itself an waits for new sound to record. Each record is labeled with time. That's the code doing I quoted here:

```
while GPIO.input(26) == False:
    timestamp = datetime.datetime.now().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
    process = subprocess.Popen ("rec -c 2 -r 192000 --buffer 50000 -b 32" + filepath + timestamp + ".wav sinc 0.1k silence 1 0.1 0.8% 1 0.4 0.8% vol 6 trim 0 8", shell = True)
    process.communicate()
```

As you can see, to finish the loop, the program waits for a GPIO-input signal (push button). I have an extra code which looks for the name of the subprocess and kills it.

But here is my problem: While the loop runs, it only "looks" for input in the millisecond between one record finishes and a new starts". If I push my button during a record, the loop continues after the record. It only breaks if I push in between.

At first, I thought maybe the while-loop is a bad choice...but if I am not wrong, the problem seems to be the running subprocess.

So here is my question: How can I accomplish this record loop but can stop/kill during a running record through user-input by GPIO. (ctrl+c won't be a viable option)

Many thanks

Comment: `while GPIO.input(26) == False:` <-- doesn't this fire multiple times whenever it's false? I don't see any use of booleans or other locking/debouncing mechanisms to keep your program from starting 100s of subprocesses. `recording = False; while GPIO.input(26) == False and not recording: recording = True; start_recording(); # recording finishes... recording = False;`

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `while` loop only checks the condition once each time through the loop. The `process.communicate()` call waits for the `rec` command to finish, so you are absolutely right - the button is only checked once, just after the `rec` and before the `timestamp = ...`.

A solution is to watch for the button in a separate thread, running in parallel with the `rec`.  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18596063/2877364) suggests using [event detection](http://sourceforge.net/p/raspberry-gpio-python/wiki/Inputs) from the RPi.GPIO library.  Try something like this:

```
should_exit = False

def my_callback(channel):
    if GPIO.input(26):
        should_exit = True

GPIO.add_event_detect(26, GPIO.RISING, callback=my_callback, bouncetime=300)

while not should_exit:
    timestamp = ...
```

The `my_callback` routine should run when the button is pressed, and set the `should_exit` flag.  Once the `rec` finishes, the `while` will check `should_exit` and terminate.  (Caution - not tested!)

Comment: many thanks, I will try it - My problem is that, I also would like to cancel the running record -but I guess - with this way I can execute the kill-script

Comment: ok, I tryed it - and the event detect works - sometimes - but it seems very unreliable

Comment: Glad it's better than nothing!  I'm afraid I don't have personal experience with RPi.GPIO.  Does the pushbutton have a proper pullup or pulldown?  Are all the connections solid?  Intermittent operation might be a hardware issue.  Also, try a loop that doesn't run `rec` but just prints a debug message and see if the button is being detected properly.

Comment: i will try it thanks. until know sometimes it works nothing, than it works 2 times in a row and stops then detecting something and there are time it works very well for a longer time but stops detecting in input then, too - maybe it's an interference between the normal GPIO.in and the detection call