# raspberry pi python gpio timer

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gpio

Hi I'm learning to code python on raspberry pi 3 model B. and playing around with GPIO.
My script makes a LED turns on when the receiving input==1 and turn off when input!=1. 
I also want to record the time when LED is turned on and time when it's turned off. (start time and end time).
I end up using multiple if/elif condition, but I'm sure there are better ways of doing this. Please enlighten me!

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
GPIO.cleanup()
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BOARD)
GPIO.setup(11,GPIO.IN, pull_up_down = GPIO.PUD_DOWN)
GPIO.setup(7,GPIO.OUT)
GPIO.output(7,0) #set ping 7 to be 0 at default
CatchTime = True
startTime = []
startTimeRead = []
endTime = []
try:
        while True:
                time.sleep(0.25)
                if (GPIO.input(11) ==1)and CatchTime==True :  #start counting
                        GPIO.output(7,1)
                        print(time.ctime())
                        startTime.append(time.time())
                        startTimeRead.append(time.ctime())
                        CatchTime = False
                elif (GPIO.input(11) ==1)and CatchTime != True : #within count
                        GPIO.output(7,1)
                        print(time.ctime())
                elif (GPIO.input(11) !=1) and CatchTime != True : #end of count
                        GPIO.output(7,0)
                        CatchTime = True
                        endTime.append(time.time())
                else:   #steady not count
                        GPIO.output(7,0)
                        CatchTime = True

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    GPIO.cleanup()


print('start time:',startTimeRead)
print('end time:',endTime)
```

Comment: this question may be more relevant to the [rasberry-pi](http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/) page or [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks @Aaron. I will seek out there as well. I'm a nooby~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the better way to do it would be to create interrupt functions for the rising and falling events. what you're doing now is referred to as [busy waiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Busy_waiting) while [polling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_(computer_science)) for an input. Interrupts are generally cleaner and more reliable. [Computerphile](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54BrU82ANww) has a nice overview on interrupts in general (more from the computer aspect of things), and a quick google search found [this](http://raspi.tv/2013/how-to-use-interrupts-with-python-on-the-raspberry-pi-and-rpi-gpio-part-3) tutorial on how to use gpio interrupts with the rasberry-pi.

Comment: Thanks Aaron, this is very educative! :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend looking at [this post (Raspberry Pi- GPIO Events in Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18596063/5559547) on the Raspberry Pi SO.  That solution shows how to use events so you don't have to run a constant loop - it will just notify you when there is a change.